# Live Microphone amplitude measurement in c#

Tags: c#, .net, input, voice, microphone

I am looking for simple solution which will return integer value of microphone input in c#. I was already checking available samples on net, but none of them worked in a x64 environment. (VS2008 + W7 x64).

Is there any simple solution that will return value of amplitude (or frequency) of microphone input in c#?

I tried NAudio without results and this: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/cswavrec.aspx?msg=2155497 without luck.

Comment: Have you tried DirectX DirectSound?

Comment: Have you tried setting your program from "Any CPU" to "32 bit only"? Most programs don't profit much from being run in 64 bit mode.

Comment: I tried that already, but no luck so far. Haven't found any simple directSound example too. I also tried SlimDX, but looks like, that there is always some trouble with all that examples. Besides in my case I need integer value with dynamic update (sampled few times per second). Anyone has some experience with that? Thanks for any help.

Comment: The math to calculate the amplitude is quite simple. You can just average the squared amplitude of the input over a time-interval. The input is typically a byte-array containing a sequence of signed shorts.

Comment: I use the code from http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Streaming_wave_audio.aspx?fid=444913&select=3094249&fr=26#xx0xx , but I've never tried it on a 64 bit OS.

Comment: One important thing to note is that to record from the microphone with most APIs the user needs to have checked the microphone in the recording volume-control. I added a menu entry in my program which uses `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("sndvol32.exe", "/R");` to make it easy for the user to change his recording settings.

Comment: Here is a very handy sample how to record microphone input with naudio maybe this can help you: http://opensebj.blogspot.com/2009/04/naudio-tutorial-5-recording-audio.html

Answer (score 2):

I reckon the easiest route to go is to use the old Windows multimedia API because it's really straight forward.

Here's the link to MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd743586(v=VS.85).aspx

What you do is that you use the `waveInOpen` function to get an input device. To figure out what device to use you don't enumerate all the devices but you can query each and one of them. The number of installed devices is returned by calling `waveInGetNumDevs`. You can then call `waveInGetDevCaps` for each device and inspect those properties.

When you have your device handle you then repeatedly call `waveInAddBuffer` to get small chunks of data. Depending on the format you specified during `waveInOpen` the bytes represent the raw audio data. Amplitude in 8 or 16-bit signed or unisnged sampled at some frequency.

You could then apply a rolling average to smooth the signal and just print that.

C# doesn't have a sound API that I know of, so what you do is that you use P/Invoke to get at the Win32 API functions. This is fairly straight forward, you only need to port small versions of the Win32 headers to be able to call them from C# directly.

If you're more hardcore you could write a wrapper library in C++/CLI. That's not that bad of an idea because it let's you use existing Windows C/C++ header files and mix C++ and managed code in intresting ways. Just be careful with the unmanaged resources and you'll have a very powerful intropability library in no time.

But there's also more advanced audio APIs starting with Windows Vista, the Windows Core Audio components which could be more interesting further along the line. But for basic I/O operation the Windows multimedia functions will get you there faster.

I've used these functions on a number of occasions when building simple software synthesizers. Sadly that code is long gone.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend SlimDX since it should work on just about any version of windows (x86 or x64) and provides the most features and flexibility.  However, it is a pain to get up and running since there are no good complete code samples.  I wrote a wrapper class to simplify its usage though so it can be called like this (I tested this code on Win7 x64):

```
    public void CaptureAudio()
    {
        using (var source = new SoundCardSource())
        {
            source.SampleRateKHz = 44.1;
            source.SampleDataReady += this.OnSampleDataReady;
            source.Start();

            // Capture 5 seconds of audio...
            Thread.Sleep(5000);

            source.Stop();
        }
    }

    private void OnSampleDataReady(object sender, SampleDataEventArgs e)
    {
        // Do something with e.Data short array on separate thread...
    }
```

Here is the source for the SlimDX wrapper class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using SlimDX.DirectSound;
using SlimDX.Multimedia;

public class SampleDataEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public SampleDataEventArgs(short[] data)
    {
        this.Data = data;
    }

    public short[] Data { get; private set; }
}

public class SoundCardSource : IDisposable
{
    private volatile bool running;
    private int bufferSize;
    private CaptureBuffer buffer;
    private CaptureBufferDescription bufferDescription;
    private DirectSoundCapture captureDevice;
    private WaveFormat waveFormat;
    private Thread captureThread;
    private List<NotificationPosition> notifications;
    private int bufferPortionCount;
    private int bufferPortionSize;
    private WaitHandle[] waitHandles;
    private double sampleRate;

    public SoundCardSource()
    {
        this.waveFormat = new WaveFormat();
        this.SampleRateKHz = 44.1;
        this.bufferSize = 2048;
    }

    public event EventHandler<SampleDataEventArgs> SampleDataReady = delegate { };

    public double SampleRateKHz
    {
        get 
        { 
            return this.sampleRate; 
        }

        set
        {
            this.sampleRate = value;

            if (this.running)
            {
                this.Restart();
            }
        }
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        if (this.running)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }

        if (this.captureDevice == null)
        {
            this.captureDevice = new DirectSoundCapture();
        }

        this.waveFormat.FormatTag = WaveFormatTag.Pcm; // Change to WaveFormatTag.IeeeFloat for float
        this.waveFormat.BitsPerSample = 16; // Set this to 32 for float
        this.waveFormat.BlockAlignment = (short)(waveFormat.BitsPerSample / 8);
        this.waveFormat.Channels = 1;
        this.waveFormat.SamplesPerSecond = (int)(this.SampleRateKHz * 1000D);
        this.waveFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond =
            this.waveFormat.SamplesPerSecond *
            this.waveFormat.BlockAlignment *
            this.waveFormat.Channels;

        this.bufferPortionCount = 2;

        this.bufferDescription.BufferBytes = this.bufferSize * sizeof(short) * bufferPortionCount;
        this.bufferDescription.Format = this.waveFormat;
        this.bufferDescription.WaveMapped = false;

        this.buffer = new CaptureBuffer(this.captureDevice, this.bufferDescription);

        this.bufferPortionSize = this.buffer.SizeInBytes / this.bufferPortionCount;
        this.notifications = new List<NotificationPosition>();

        for (int i = 0; i < this.bufferPortionCount; i++)
        {
            NotificationPosition notification = new NotificationPosition();
            notification.Offset = this.bufferPortionCount - 1 + (bufferPortionSize * i);
            notification.Event = new AutoResetEvent(false);
            this.notifications.Add(notification);
        }

        this.buffer.SetNotificationPositions(this.notifications.ToArray());
        this.waitHandles = new WaitHandle[this.notifications.Count];

        for (int i = 0; i < this.notifications.Count; i++)
        {
            this.waitHandles[i] = this.notifications[i].Event;
        }

        this.captureThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.CaptureThread));
        this.captureThread.IsBackground = true;

        this.running = true;
        this.captureThread.Start();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        this.running = false;

        if (this.captureThread != null)
        {
            this.captureThread.Join();
            this.captureThread = null;
        }

        if (this.buffer != null)
        {
            this.buffer.Dispose();
            this.buffer = null;
        }

        if (this.notifications != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < this.notifications.Count; i++)
            {
                this.notifications[i].Event.Close();
            }

            this.notifications.Clear();
            this.notifications = null;
        }
    }

    public void Restart()
    {
        this.Stop();
        this.Start();
    }

    private void CaptureThread()
    {
        int bufferPortionSamples = this.bufferPortionSize / sizeof(float);

        // Buffer type must match this.waveFormat.FormatTag and this.waveFormat.BitsPerSample
        short[] bufferPortion = new short[bufferPortionSamples];
        int bufferPortionIndex;

        this.buffer.Start(true);

        while (this.running)
        {
            bufferPortionIndex = WaitHandle.WaitAny(this.waitHandles);

            this.buffer.Read(
                bufferPortion,
                0,
                bufferPortionSamples,
                bufferPortionSize * Math.Abs((bufferPortionIndex - 1) % bufferPortionCount));

            this.SampleDataReady(this, new SampleDataEventArgs(bufferPortion));
        }

        this.buffer.Stop();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            this.Stop();

            if (this.captureDevice != null)
            {
                this.captureDevice.Dispose();
                this.captureDevice = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's fully multi-threaded to minimize latency.  I originally wrote it for a real-time signal processing analysis tool and used float output instead of short but I modified the code sample to match your requested usage.  If you need frequency data I would use http://www.mathdotnet.com/Neodym.aspx or http://www.exocortex.org/dsp/ for a good C# FFT library.